# Desabilitar ou Esconder elesmentos de mesma classe

Tags: javascript

Preciso esconder ou desabilitar os elementos de mesma classe caso o valor escolhido no select seja 0.

```
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="status_imovel" id="statusImovel" onchange="bloquearPlaceholder(this)">
                    <option selected value="0">Aberta</option>
                    <option value="1">Recusada</option>
                    <option value="2">Fechada</option>
                </select>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
imagem referente ao console.log do document.querySelectorAll(".desabilitar"]

```
 <script>
                    function bloquearPlaceholder()
                   {
                      const desabilitarInput = document.querySelectorAll(".desabilitar");

                      if (document.getElementsByName('status_imovel').value != 0){

                        desabilitarInput.style.visibility = 'hidden';


                      }              
                                        </script>
```

Comment: Olá amigo, infelizmente não consegui entender o problema que estás tentando resolver. Tu poderias explicar com mais detalhes qual teu objetivo, o que tentaste e quais os erros ou comportamentos inesperados que estás tendo?

Comment: com a escolha da option de value="0" do select, espero esconder ou inativar os, inputs, selects e botões que possuem a mesma classe.

Answer (score -1):

Considerando que na sua pergunta, faltou colocar o elemento que será ocultado, criei um DIV com a CLASSE `desabilitar` e fiz um css básico para facilitar a visualização.

Lembrando que `Document.querySelectorAll()` retorna uma lista, assim como `getElementsByName`. Logo, em ambos os casos, é necessário utilizar a posição do elemento `[0]`.

Segue o código funcionando:

```js
function bloquearPlaceholder(){
  const desabilitarInput = document.querySelectorAll(".desabilitar");
  if (document.getElementsByName('status_imovel')[0].value != '0'){
     desabilitarInput[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }else{
     desabilitarInput[0].style.visibility = 'visible';  
  }
}
```

```css
.desabilitar{
  display:block;
  color:red;
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:2em;
  margin:2em;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="status_imovel" id="statusImovel" onchange="bloquearPlaceholder(this)">
                    <option selected value="0">Aberta</option>
                    <option value="1">Recusada</option>
                    <option value="2">Fechada</option>
                </select>
                
                
                <div class="desabilitar">Estou sendo visto!</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado, desculpe pela má pergunta, vou melhorar. Mas preciso desabilitar ou esconder todos os elementos do array como mostrado na imagem, criado a partir da constante const desabilitarInput = document.querySelectorAll(".desabilitar")